# Asana oAuth with GTMOAuth2 - unable to login with Google account

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, asana

using the latest GTMOAuth2 for mac, regular oAuth authentication with username and password works fine. But clicking sign in with google account does not present the google login page.

[image]

how can we fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly GTMOAuth2 suppresses/blocks pop-ups - Google Auth will open in a separate pop-up window. Perhaps there's a setting to allow pop-ups in GTMOAuth2?

Comment: Thanks @agnoster, you showed the path to fix it..   webkit wants us to implement the `-(WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` to handle open pop ups and windows. For **GTMOAuth2** too we need to implement this method in **GTMOAuth2WindowController** to pop a new window for the request. That fixed the problem.